# Is it possible to parameterize a query inside pl sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-injection

The stored procedures being written here currently concats the parameters to the queries:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM Names 
    WHERE Name = ' || prmName || ' 
 ORDER BY ' || prmSortField
```

Is it possible to parameterize this query inside the stored procedure? Possibly like:

```
query = 'select * From Names Where Name = @name Order By ' || prmSortField
call(query, prmName)
```

*Note:* 
In case you wonder why we do so, there are two common parameters for our sp's: `sortFieldIndex` and `sortDirection`. Since we cannot directly parameterize these, the query is dynamically generated. But other parameters make the queries open for injection. So I am looking a way to parameterize some of the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.  Use [cursors](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm).

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 (job VARCHAR2, max_wage NUMBER) IS
    SELECT * FROM employees WHERE job_id = job AND salary > max_wage;
BEGIN
  FOR person IN c1('CLERK', 3000)
  LOOP
     -- process data record
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name = ' || person.last_name || ', salary = ' ||
                         person.salary || ', Job Id = ' || person.job_id );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What about the OP's prmSortField variable? How can you parameterize the ordering field without dynamic queries?

Answer (score 4):

For a dynamic query with bind values, do this:

```
procedure p (prmName varchar2, prmSortField varchar2)
is
    query varchar2(100);
    rc sys_refcursor;
    names_rec names%rowtype;
begin
    query = 'select * From Names Where Name = :name Order By ' || prmSortField
    open rc for query using prmName;
    loop
        fetch rc into names_rec;
        exit when rc%notfound;
        -- process this row
    end loop;
    close rc;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

For a more elaborate procedure that supports optional parameter values (but uses sys context), check out the following post on Asktom.com

[PRATTY -- Thanks for the question regarding 'CURSOR'...](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1288401763279#4988761718663)